# Задача на цикл for

Tags: java

Решаю "Златопольский Д.М - Сборник задач по программированию". Задача 5.57: Известны оценки двух учеников по 4 предметам. Определить сумму оценок каждого ученика. Я решил задачу, но думаю, что нужно использовать только 1 цикл.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Zlat557  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum1 = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0;
        
        for (int t = 1; t <= 4; t++) {
            System.out.print("Object #" + t + ": ");
            int a = read.nextInt();
            sum1 += a;
        }
        System.out.println(sum1);
        
        for (int g = 1; g <= 4; g++) {
            System.out.print("Object #" + g + ": ");
            int b = read.nextInt();
            sum2 += b;
        }
        System.out.println(sum2);
    }
}
```

Comment: *думаю, что нужно использовать только 1 цикл.* Можно и 1 цикл. Но профита с этого не получите - уберёте накладные расходы на организацию одного цикла, зато приобретёте дополнительно расчёт, к какому из учеников прикладывать очередное прочитанное значение. Впрочем, в учебных целях это сделать будет полезно.

Comment: Вполне нормальное решение. Если структуру циклов поменять, то решение можно поменять для любых N учеников и K оценок каждого из них (при этом всё так же останется всего 2 цикла).

Comment: @Akina Спасибо, если вам не трудно можете решить эту задачу с одним циклом?

Comment: Могу. Но задача учебная и довольно простая, требующая только логики и аккуратности - посему просто не стану. Делайте самостоятельно. А если не получится - приходите, показывайте сделанное и в чём затык, поможем.

Comment: @Akina буду пытаться.

Comment: @Akina я решил, но хочется сделать по другому. У меня сначала идет студент№1 и его 1-я оценка, точно также со вторым. 
for (int t = 1; t <= 4; t++) {
   System.out.println("Student #1");
   System.out.print("Object #" + t + ": ");
   int a = read.nextInt();
   sum1 += a;
   
   System.out.println("Student #2");
   System.out.print("Object #" + t + ": ");
   int b = read.nextInt();
   sum2 += b;
   
   System.out.println();

Answer (score 1):

Если оценки уже известны, то вводить их не надо, я думаю. Поэтому давайте условимся, что мы как бы получили из вне. Тогда можно написать такой код:

```
public class Zlat557 {
    
import java.util.Scanner;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int [] scores1 = new int [4];
    int [] scores2 = new int [4];
    ArrayList base = new ArrayList(); 
    
    scores1 = {90, 70, 100, 80};
    // Оценки как бы были в базе данных
    base.add(scores1);
    // Пришлось ввести оценки студента
    scores2 = newSturentsScore(4, " ");
    base.add(scores2);
    for (int i = 0; i < base.length(); ++i){ 
    System.out.println("Sum of scores of " + (i+1) + "student  is: " + sumOfScores(base.get(i)));
    }
    }
    private int SumOfScores (int [] scores)  {
    int sum = 0;
      for (int i =0; i < scores.length(); ++i) {
      sum += scores[i];
      }
    return sum;
    }
   private int [] newSturentsScore (int listLength, String separator){
   Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter the student`s scores separated by" + separator);
   int [] studentsScores = new int [listLength];

   String inputStr = read.nextString();
   String [] strScores = inputStr.split(separator);
   for (int i = 0; i< listLength; ++i) {
   studentsScores[i] = strScores[i].parseInt();
   }
   return studentsScores;
   }

   
}
```

Тут подсчет суммы и ввод оценок студента разделен на отдельные функции. В качестве источника оценок я использовал расширяющийся массив `ArrayList`, база оценок универа. У него есть методы `remove` и `add` позволяющие удалять и добавлять элементы.

Comment: Я массивы еще  не прошел, но спасибо

Comment: @user436358 ничего страшного, что не прошли. Тут главная функция sumOfScores, в нее можно принимать отдельно 4 оценки. Все остальное — обвязка.

Comment: спасибо, хотел спросить. В intellij idea русский текст отображается ?

Comment: @SmaugDr То есть "отображается"? Есть русская версия программы

Comment: @SmaugDr писать по-русски тоже можно, если Вы это имели в виду.

Comment: Спасибо
У меня за это время появился еще одни вопрос. А почему java не может прочесть дробные числа. Только, что решил задачу 5,34: 1 + 1/3 + 1/3^(2) + ... + 1/3^(n)[https://vk.com/doc44301783_449765207?hash=b6f2c71092435bdfe0&dl=4f700739ba5c89b95d]. Нужно такую последовательность написать, я ее решил, но 1/3 представил как рациональное число 0,3333.

Comment: @SmaugDr Тут принято отдельные вопросы задавать, как вопросы, а не писать в комментариях, это не форум. Сходите в тур https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour и Почитайте справку https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Я решил с одним циклом, но выглядит не очень.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Zlat557 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum1 = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0;
        
        for (int t = 1; t <= 4; t++) {
            System.out.println("Student #1");
            System.out.print("Object #" + t + ": ");
            int a = read.nextInt();
            sum1 += a;
            
            System.out.println("Student #2");
            System.out.print("Object #" + t + ": ");
            int b = read.nextInt();
            sum2 += b;
            
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Suuma #1 studenta: " + sum1 + "\n" + "Summa #2 studenta: " + sum2);
    }
}
```

Однако, я сделал с 2 циклами и выглядит это намного лучше.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Zlat557a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        double sum1 = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0;
        
        System.out.println("Student #1");
        for (int t = 1; t <= 4; t++) {
            System.out.print("Object #" + t + ": ");
            int a = read.nextInt();
            sum1 += a;
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "Student #2");
        for (int g = 1; g <= 4; g++) {
            System.out.print("Object #" + g + ": ");
            int b = read.nextInt();
            sum2 += b;
        }
        System.out.println("\n" + "Suuma #1 studenta: " + sum1 + "\n" + "Summa #2 studenta: " + sum2);
    }
}
```

Comment: А представьте, если студентов будет 100 :)

Comment: А зачем? В условие задачи говорится только про 2 учеников